# Terminology: what do you call two words that rhyme but whose endings aren't spelled the same?

Tags: terminology

Examples:

- Buzz/Does/Was
- Too/Blue/Grew/Flu/Through/Threw

I overheard a claim that this phenomenon is only present in English and Japanese. I'm not well versed in enough other languages to know whether this true, and I find it unlikely to be so. When I attempted to search for examples, I discovered that I don't know what this is called, or if it even has a name.

So, is there a name for groups of words with these relationships?

<s>Bonus points: do you know of other languages in which this phenomenon exists?</s>

Comment: Counterexamples: Polish Bóg/tuk; German Blatt/Kat/Stadt

Comment: This will occur in every language whose writing system is not largely phonetic, so English is a prime candidate. French is another: _eau_, _aux_, _haut_, _os_, _aulx_, and _oh_ are all pronounced exactly the same (and therefore rhyme), but are spelt quite differently. And Irish is fab for this: _an bhfaighidh_ and _an ghaoth_ are exact homophones in some dialects—despite their spellings, both are pronounced /ə wiː/ ‘a wee’! Arguably, Japanese is one of the languages where this **doesn’t** occur, since the two sound-based writing systems used for Japanese are completely phonetic.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: The Japanese kana aren't completely phonetic, just mostly. There are correspondences between multiple spellings to single sounds even in the present standard, which is the result of relatively recent spelling reform. The "rhymes" framing of this Q isn't really applicable because of the syllabic nature of the writing system, so it's normal for rhyming Japanese words to not end in the same sequence of characters, but e.g. there's the di/zi and du/zu spelling distinctions, as well as some ambiguities related to the spelling of long /eː/ and /oː/.

Comment: (IIRC, long vowels vs. hiatus can be ambiguous in some cases also.)

Comment: @sumelic That is true—you could have ぢ and じ rhyme, or おう and おお (or even, I suppose, をう), so even in Japanese you could have a limited amount of this. Of course, if you treat ideographic writing systems as ‘alphabets’, you have an immense amount of this to go on with. There are quite literally _hundreds_ of characters pronounced _yì_ Chinese, and if you consider all those ‘rhymes’, then you’ll be inundated before you know it. But that seems somewhat disingenuous.

Comment: Rhyming is purely phonetic. Spelling has nothing to do with it at all.

Comment: Guys...all the erudition aside, does this belong here or on Linguistics.SE? 'cuz from where I am sitting, it seems we are citing examples from _other_ languages.

Comment: @Cascabel When the experts on this site converse among themselves it is truly a privilege to be a spectator.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because words that rhyme are simply words that rhyme, regardless of the degree of similarity in their spellings.

Comment: I have removed the part of the question which is not relevant to English.

Comment: So, this is embarassing. I thought I had posted this in Linguistics, not in EL&U. Close if you want.

Comment: @MikeHarris obviously. But words that sound exactly the same but which aren’t (necessarily) spelled the same have a name: homophone. I was just wondering if there was something similar for word groupings in which the thing that sounds the same is just part of the word (specifically the last part), rather than the entire word.

Comment: @Davo: That sounds like an answer to the question. Why do you believe that it is a reason to close it?

Comment: As said in the preceding comments, *rhyme* is about the sound, and spelling is incidental. However, I'd see this Q as related to a term for words **that rhyme but do not end in similar spelling**, a subset of "rhymes."

Comment: Words that end with **the same vowel** or **consonant sound**

Comment: It's known as "English".

Comment: In most dialects of British English, "was" and "does"/"buzz" do not rhyme.

Comment: Homophones are often not spelled differently. Consider _bear_ (v) and _bear_ (n), which have nothing to do with each other except in pronunciation, and differ in spelling from _bare_ (adj), another homophone. In fact, with many verbs, reified transitives are considered separate verbs, hence homophones, viz intransitive _shine, shone, shone_ vs transitive _shine, shined, shined_.

Answer (score 8):

I don't think there's an established word for it.

It's kind of the opposite of an *eye rhyme*, where the words are spelled the same but don't actually end with the same sounds (e.g., *show* and *now*). So you could call it an *ear rhyme*.

But usually, we just use the word *rhyme* for this, and don't distinguish between the cases where the words end with the same letters or not.

There's a word for it in French: *rime pour l'oreille* (literally, *rhyme for the ear*), which is a rhyme which doesn't necessarily satisfy the French poetic criteria to be a *rime pour l'œil<sup>1</sup>* (literally *rhyme for the eye*).

<sup>1</sup> In classical French poetry, words had to rhyme both for the eye and the ear. The rules for *rimes pour l'œil* probably seem a little esoteric for English speakers; for example, *doux* and *nous* were allowable rhymes, but you weren't allowed to rhyme
these words with *tout*, despite the fact that their pronunciations are *do, noo,* and *too*.

Comment: [Homograph, homophone, homonym, heteronym](http://www.magickeys.com/books/riddles/words.html). It looks established that 'homophone is the answer.

Comment: @Mitch: *rough* and *ruff* are homophones. *tough* and *cuff* not homophones, but are an instance of what the OP is asking about. There is possibly a word for it in French.

Comment: The word for it in French is indeed *ear rhyme*, that is, *rime pour l'oreille*.

Comment: Oh, I see, similar but not identical. I think the only distinction in English is sounding the same (whatever the spelling, same ending or not) called simply 'rhyme', vs spelling the same at the last syllable or so (what ever the pronunciation) called 'spelling rhyme'. And no special terms for rhyming sound and spelling same vs rhyming but not spelled same.

Answer (score -4):

It's called 'assonance' meaning 'sounds the same'. As you note, words do not need to be spelled the same in order to sound the same.

‘Sounds the same’ is what assonance means.
https://www.google.co.id/search?q=etymology+assonance&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en-id&client=safari

Comment: There I thought assonance was - broadly - as Julie Walter's *Rita* puts it, "when you get the rhyme wrong…" ie, the words appear as they ought to but in fact don't quite sound the same.

Comment: I'm going from my sense of the origin of the word, @RobbieGoodwin - son - is sound. It's origin is from sounds like, or I think it means 'resonates with' Think of it like, 2 bells sounding together, resonating. I think that's what it means.  Here's a link: https://www.google.com.sg/search?q=etymology+assonance&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en-sg&client=safari

Comment: Use citations to defend your answers. I did some research, and didn't find anything to support your claim.

Comment: Assonance is rhyming *mud* and *love*. Same vowel, but not necessarily the same consonant. Eye rhyme is rhyming *mind* and *wind*.